# XML DataSet Merging

Tags: c#, xml, out-of-memory

**Final version:**

I'm sorry for previous unclear question with bunch of random code. Basically what I need to do is to merge a lot of XML files (around 100 - 200 at once) from one folder into one file, here is an example of input and output of files:

**File 1**

```
<dokumenty  xmlns="http://www.somelink.pl/otherlink">
    <info>
        <komentarz>Text1</komentarz>
        <wersja>Text1</wersja>
        <copyright>Text1</copyright>
        <data-utworzenia>Text1</data-utworzenia>
        <system>
            <producent>Text1</producent>
            <symbol>Text1</symbol>
            <email>Text1</email>
            <wersja>Text1</wersja>
            <nazwa>Text1</nazwa>
        </system>
    </info>
    <kontrahenci>
        <kontrahent>
            <id-knt-ks>Text1</id-knt-ks>
            <nazwa>Text1</nazwa>
            <id-knt>Text1</id-knt>
        </kontrahent>
        <kontrahent>
            <id-knt-ks>Text3</id-knt-ks>
            <nazwa>Text3</nazwa>
            <id-knt>Text3</id-knt>
        </kontrahent>
    </kontrahenci>
    <towary>
        <towar>
            <id-towaru>Text1</id-towaru>
            <nazwa>Text1</nazwa>
            <id-towaru-ks>Text1</id-towaru-ks>
        </towar>
    </towary>
    <zamowienia>
        <zamowienie>
            <naglowek>
                <id-zamowienia>Text1</id-zamowienia>
                <tylko-komplet>Text1</tylko-komplet>
                <id-knt-dostawcy>Text1</id-knt-dostawcy>
                <data-wystawienia>Text1</data-wystawienia>
                <nr-zamowienia>Text1</nr-zamowienia>
                <id-knt-odbiorcy>Text1</id-knt-odbiorcy>
                <potwierdzanie>Text1</potwierdzanie>
            </naglowek>
            <pozycje>
                <pozycja>
                    <id-towaru>Text1</id-towaru>
                    <id-poz-zamowienia>Text1</id-poz-zamowienia>
                    <nr-poz-zamowienia>Text1</nr-poz-zamowienia>
                    <ilosc>Text1</ilosc>
                </pozycja>
            </pozycje>
        </zamowienie>
    </zamowienia>
</dokumenty>
```

**File 2**

```
<dokumenty  xmlns="http://www.somelink.pl/otherlink">
    <info>
        <komentarz>Text2</komentarz>
        <wersja>Text2</wersja>
        <copyright>Text2</copyright>
        <data-utworzenia>Text2</data-utworzenia>
        <system>
            <producent>Text2</producent>
            <symbol>Text2</symbol>
            <email>Text2</email>
            <wersja>Text2</wersja>
            <nazwa>Text2</nazwa>
        </system>
    </info>
    <kontrahenci>
        <kontrahent>
            <id-knt-ks>Text2</id-knt-ks>
            <nazwa>Text2</nazwa>
            <id-knt>Text2</id-knt>
        </kontrahent>
    </kontrahenci>
    <towary>
        <towar>
            <id-towaru>Text2</id-towaru>
            <nazwa>Text2</nazwa>
            <id-towaru-ks>Text2</id-towaru-ks>
        </towar>
    </towary>
    <zamowienia>
        <zamowienie>
            <naglowek>
                <id-zamowienia>Text2</id-zamowienia>
                <tylko-komplet>Text2</tylko-komplet>
                <id-knt-dostawcy>Text2</id-knt-dostawcy>
                <data-wystawienia>Text2</data-wystawienia>
                <nr-zamowienia>Text2</nr-zamowienia>
                <id-knt-odbiorcy>Text2</id-knt-odbiorcy>
                <potwierdzanie>Text2</potwierdzanie>
            </naglowek>
            <pozycje>
                <pozycja>
                    <id-towaru>Text2</id-towaru>
                    <id-poz-zamowienia>Text2</id-poz-zamowienia>
                    <nr-poz-zamowienia>Text2</nr-poz-zamowienia>
                    <ilosc>Text2</ilosc>
                </pozycja>
                <pozycja>
                    <id-towaru>Text3</id-towaru>
                    <id-poz-zamowienia>Text3</id-poz-zamowienia>
                    <nr-poz-zamowienia>Text3</nr-poz-zamowienia>
                    <ilosc>Text3</ilosc>
                </pozycja>
            </pozycje>
        </zamowienie>
    </zamowienia>
</dokumenty>
```

And get new XML file like this:

```
<dokumenty  xmlns="http://www.somelink.pl/otherlink">
    <info>
        <komentarz>Text1</komentarz>
        <wersja>Text1</wersja>
        <copyright>Text1</copyright>
        <data-utworzenia>Text1</data-utworzenia>
        <system>
            <producent>Text1</producent>
            <symbol>Text1</symbol>
            <email>Text1</email>
            <wersja>Text1</wersja>
            <nazwa>Text1</nazwa>
        </system>
    </info>
    <kontrahenci>
        <kontrahent>
            <id-knt-ks>Text1</id-knt-ks>
            <nazwa>Text1</nazwa>
            <id-knt>Text1</id-knt>
        </kontrahent>
        <kontrahent>
            <id-knt-ks>Text3</id-knt-ks>
            <nazwa>Text3</nazwa>
            <id-knt>Text3</id-knt>
        </kontrahent>
        <kontrahent>
            <id-knt-ks>Text2</id-knt-ks>
            <nazwa>Text2</nazwa>
            <id-knt>Text2</id-knt>
        </kontrahent>
    </kontrahenci>
    <towary>
        <towar>
            <id-towaru>Text1</id-towaru>
            <nazwa>Text1</nazwa>
            <id-towaru-ks>Text1</id-towaru-ks>
        </towar>
        <towar>
            <id-towaru>Text2</id-towaru>
            <nazwa>Text2</nazwa>
            <id-towaru-ks>Text2</id-towaru-ks>
        </towar>
    </towary>
    <zamowienia>
      <zamowienie>
          <naglowek>
              <id-zamowienia>Text1</id-zamowienia>
              <tylko-komplet>Text1</tylko-komplet>
              <id-knt-dostawcy>Text1</id-knt-dostawcy>
              <data-wystawienia>Text1</data-wystawienia>
              <nr-zamowienia>Text1</nr-zamowienia>
              <id-knt-odbiorcy>Text1</id-knt-odbiorcy>
              <potwierdzanie>Text1</potwierdzanie>
          </naglowek>
          <pozycje>
              <pozycja>
                  <id-towaru>Text1</id-towaru>
                  <id-poz-zamowienia>Text1</id-poz-zamowienia>
                  <nr-poz-zamowienia>Text1</nr-poz-zamowienia>
                  <ilosc>Text1</ilosc>
              </pozycja>
          </pozycje>
      </zamowienie>
        <zamowienie>
            <naglowek>
                <id-zamowienia>Text2</id-zamowienia>
                <tylko-komplet>Text2</tylko-komplet>
                <id-knt-dostawcy>Text2</id-knt-dostawcy>
                <data-wystawienia>Text2</data-wystawienia>
                <nr-zamowienia>Text2</nr-zamowienia>
                <id-knt-odbiorcy>Text2</id-knt-odbiorcy>
                <potwierdzanie>Text2</potwierdzanie>
            </naglowek>
            <pozycje>
                <pozycja>
                    <id-towaru>Text2</id-towaru>
                    <id-poz-zamowienia>Text2</id-poz-zamowienia>
                    <nr-poz-zamowienia>Text2</nr-poz-zamowienia>
                    <ilosc>Text2</ilosc>
                </pozycja>
                <pozycja>
                    <id-towaru>Text3</id-towaru>
                    <id-poz-zamowienia>Text3</id-poz-zamowienia>
                    <nr-poz-zamowienia>Text3</nr-poz-zamowienia>
                    <ilosc>Text3</ilosc>
                </pozycja>
            </pozycje>
        </zamowienie>
    </zamowienia>
</dokumenty>
```

It would be great if IDs where distinct, but sorting is not needed.

I started to learn about LINQ and XSLT files so it's totally new thing for me, that's why there was such a mess in previous version of question.

---

**Edit:**

So with help of Alexander Petrov I got almost what I wanted, but the code doesn't copy XML values, only nodes. Here is a part that does it:

```
var kontrahent = source.Elements("kontrahenci").Nodes();
kontrahenci.Add(kontrahent);

var towar = source.Elements("towary").Elements("towar").Nodes();
towary.Add(towar);

var zamowienie = source.Elements("zamowienia").Elements("zamowienie").Nodes();
zamowienia.Add(zamowienie);
```

And it doesn't matter if there is `Nodes()` or `Elements()` at the end.

Comment: Show the accurate xml sample and the desired result.

Comment: Ok, I added XML samples I have to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Specify your real namespace.
XNamespace ns = "http://www.somelink.pl/otherlink";

var info = new XElement(ns + "info");
var kontrahenci = new XElement(ns + "kontrahenci");
var towary = new XElement(ns + "towary");
var zamowienia = new XElement(ns + "zamowienia");

foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.xml"))
{
    var source = XElement.Load(file);

    var infoElements = source.Element(ns + "info")?.Elements();
    info.Add(infoElements);

    var kontrahenciElements = source.Element(ns + "kontrahenci")?.Elements();
    kontrahenci.Add(kontrahenciElements);

    var towaryElements = source.Element(ns + "towary")?.Elements();
    towary.Add(towaryElements);

    var zamowieniaElements = source.Element(ns + "zamowienia")?.Elements();
    zamowienia.Add(zamowieniaElements);
}

var result = new XElement(ns + "dokumenty", info, kontrahenci, towary, zamowienia);
result.Save(filename);
```

Comment: It seems like something I need but

    var comments = source.Element("info").Elements();

gives me:

>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @MikołajKlimas - It means you have no `info` node in the XML. Do you have namespaces in XML?

Comment: I managed to handle this problem, but right know it copies only XML nodes, without any values (i get the basic structure of wanted XML file in output), I'll put in answer this part of code which copies elements.

Comment: When I changed Element("info") to Elements("info") it worked almost fine.

Comment: Doesn't work either. Result have only those 4 empty nodes from the beginning... Maybe there is something wrong with XMLs?

Comment: @MikołajKlimas - It works well with those XML files that you provided.

Comment: I can't share the originals XMLs, but I can see that it works on this samples. All right so I'll try to work it out on my own, thank you for your time and help sir!

Comment: @MikołajKlimas - Maybe your XML have namespaces? Then you must specify it in C# code.

Comment: Yeah, I found the problem. The <dokumenty> in original files also have xmlns part which creates troubles. I thought about deleting it somehow?

Comment: I edited XMLs to add namespaces. Sorry for a problem, sir.